# Determine $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ by Limit Laws

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/922970/695705), there is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$; and how can I conclude  $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ doesn't exist from it, without using L'Hopital Rule?

I tried this way:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}=1\cdot\pm\infty$$
Yet I doubt myself because I know the limit law applies only when both limits exist, which really confuses me in many cases of using limit laws reversely.

I would be thankful for your help!

Comment: To apply limit laws, limits must exist.

Comment: @Gune Then does it mean my attempt is actually invalid?

Comment: It does indeed. We can only say 

$$\lim f(x)g(x) = \lim f(x) \cdot \lim g(x)$$

whenever the individual limits on the right-hand side exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the following...

Let $b_n$ be a any bounded sequence and $c_n$ be any unbounded sequence.

Form the product sequence $a_n$ where $a_n = b_n c_n$

If $b_n = 0$ for all $n$ then $a_n$ converges.

Darn, and I wanted to state the following as true:

$\quad$ The sequence $a_n$ can't converge to any real number.

Could $a_n$ converge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$?

If you are interested in extended limits from the left and right sides then this is the 'scoop':

$\quad \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(\frac{\sin x}{x})(\frac{1}{x})= (\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin x}{x})(\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{x})= +1 \times +\infty = +\infty$

$\quad \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}(\frac{\sin x}{x})(\frac{1}{x})= (\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin x}{x})(\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{x})= +1 \times -\infty = -\infty$

Comment: Thank you, that helps; but is it legal to extend limits like this when one of them doesn't exist? (You may refer to Eevee Trainer's comment on the question.)

Comment: If extended limits are in play then the limit of a product is the product of the limits but you have to be wary of the [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) $0 \times \pm\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin x}{x}.\frac{1}{x}=+\infty $

$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{\sin x}{x}.\frac{1}{x}=-\infty $

So there is no limit

Answer (score 2):

It appears we may assume that the limit $\sin(x)/x \to 1$ (as $x \to 0$) is known. This establishes an asymptotic equivalence between $\sin(x)$ and $x$ as $x\to 0$. Therefore, we can swap these expressions in the limit, and therefore

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1 x$$

This limit obviously does not exist.